# binding backbone events in jqMobi Nav, or when the dom elements are duplicated in the dom

Tags: backbone.js, jqmobi

I've been porting my app to use jqMobi and jqUI, but I've run into a problem with backbone delegating events.

The way jqUI creates a side nav bar is umm.... interesting to say the least.

Each panel can have a distinct nav bar, but the nav bar is never actually visible to the user, you populate the nav bar, and then jqUI copies the html into the `div#menu` element.

My view is fairly straightforward

```
MyApp.Views.UserMenu = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: 'nav#user_menu',

  initialize: function(){
    //empty out and unbind in-case it is already populated
    $(this.el).empty().unbind();

    this.render();
  },

  events: {
    "click div#add_friend": "new_friend"
  },

  render: function(){
    $(this.el).append(HandlebarsTemplates['friends/new_friend']());

    // here I am trying to change the 'el' to point to where the menu is in the DOM
    this.el = 'div#menu';                        
    this.delegateEvents();
    return this;       
  },

  new_friend: function(){
    alert('clicked');
  }
});
```

I've tried changing the `el` to the `div#menu` after populating the `nav`, but that isn't working. I've also tried populating the `div#menu` directly, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any suggestions? I'm assuming the issue is that the elements are being moved, but it could be something else, and maybe I'm not sure how to debug the other case.

Comment: Have you tried [`setElement`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-setElement)?

Comment: @muistooshort amazing!! thank you, I wasn't even thinking the solution would be in backbone as it is such a rare case. If you put setElement as the answer, I'll accept it. Cheers

Comment: @muistooshort, actually a bit of a bonus round here if I may, I've got a nested view, and am trying to bind those events through setElement, but so far, no joy.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about this nested view? Maybe even a demo on jsfiddle.net, [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/RRXnK/) has the Backbone stuff already set up.

Comment: Side comment.  jqUi was designed for people who do NOT use frameworks...it's basic/simple/powerful.  So while it seems "dumb" to you, think of the person who knows basic HTML, it's easy compared to something like backbone :)

Comment: @Ian, Don't sell yourself short, it's as 'dumb' as Twitter bootstrap. You've built something really amazing. You've done the heavy lifting of creating a consistent UX with linked navigation and it's speedier and quicker to build on then the previous version I had built. I love it! But there are some interesting quirks to get used to. I'll send you a seperate e-mail.